# Calculate tax USA Ecommerce asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, e-commerce

I am working on an auction portal and i want to generate invoice with all the shipping charges and applicable tax based on state and city.

Is there any web service or api for calculating tax for an auction portal products ?

I would not like to store all the information in the database, i want it to be on the fly dynamic.

Thanks

Comment: Simply Googling "Sales Tax API" seems to bring back a great deal of companies offering Sales Tax API services.  Are you looking for something more unique?

Comment: no thanks. i got it done long back. :)